# TV show Identification - Racing battles

Tags: story-identification, tv

I’m looking for a TV show from roughly the late noughties (I would say 2007-2012?) shown in the UK. The basic theme of the show includes battle races, in which drives sit within a large circular vehicles as their monsters battle each other (similar style to Yu-Gi-Oh!). A core plot theme I remember includes some form of ‘shadow battles’ in which the shape of the course is drawn out across the landscape in the shape of the villain monster. Hopefully this sparks somebody’s memory as this has been bugging me for months!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this CGI or more traditional-looking animation?

Comment: Also, if you know of any similar shows that aren't the one you're looking for, please tell us the names of those shows so we don't waste any time investigating them or submit them as answers.

Comment: Castle Kingdom? This is a bizarre show where a person and their monster are in large circular vehicles and eventually race (after competing in a trivia game show or something). https://youtu.be/ZF3KscW6ffc?t=858

Comment: @JackBNimble, the name of that show is Kerwhizz: "Castle Kingdom" is the name of that particular episode, I think. Kerwhizz is still available on Cbeebies in some form, by the look of things. It's aimed at 4-6 year olds, and I thought of it first, too, but I can't really see any similarities between that and Yu-Gi-Oh!

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your support so far. I can confirm Kerwizz is not the show I’m looking for, the show I’m looking for is aimed at an older ‘early teenage' audiences. I think it may of originally aired on the channel ‘Kix’. To confirm the show us regular animation and not CGI